# teminal text entery problem

Tags: command-line

After a command is entered in a terminal I am then asked for a password but the terminal freezes and won't let me enter the password. How do I fix this.

Comment: Did the command end with a `&` by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

when you type the password there, it seems to be freeze. but actual thing which happening is you type password and terminal doesn't show it up. so enter the full password even it doesn't shows and hit enter.